# How do I render field outside node

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

For custom content type page I used this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    if (isset($vars['node'])) {
      // If the node type is "blog_madness" the template suggestion will be "page--blog-madness.tpl.php".
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
    }
}
```

So now it means I can use page.tpl.php for my custom content type pages. So for the default Basic Page the template page is page--page.tpl.php and I did test it and it works. Except this:

I am trying to render some field outside . So I used this: `<?php print render($content['field_banner']); ?>` right outside `<div id="content" class="column" role="main">` but it's not printing.

I was told this has something to do with node_load. But I'm not experienced with that.

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful if you would update your post with a brief explanation of what your purpose is. Doing so not only helps people understand your question, they can also suggest alternative methods if a better way exists. Cheers -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to load the node object to get the field value, something like this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);
```

Comment: The loaded node is typically available in the `$variables` array passed to `template_preprocess_page()` when you are on a node view page.

Comment: Wait, so where do I put this?

Comment: @MPD, I was under the impression definition that not a node page. and yes` template_preprocess_page()` or `hook_preprocess_page()` will have the node variables so no need to load the node.

Comment: Please take a look at @MPD comments before, if this is a node page you should get the value in the variables array. I will update my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can load node again in other place and render it fully or partially. Via block or something else. Node load is hard operation, use module [entitycache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache) to load the same nodes faster.

Comment: But I need only one field.